# DAshboard refresh

Tags: dashboard

Anyone can explain why Salesforce dashboards don't auto-refresh?
I am on Enterprise edition and Lightning version.
I also don't see the option of scheduling a refresh in lightning for dashboards.
Any tips highly appreciated.

Comment: Which dashboard is that? Reports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard feature yet to perform an Auto-Refresh on the Dashboard at this moment, unfortunately. This is still an idea posted on IdeaExchange as seen here:

Dashboard Auto-Refresh - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000KBz3AAG

**Message from the Idea Exchange Moderator**

Hi Everyone- the product team reviewing this request.  As you can imagine, enabling a feature like this requires careful consideration to assess potential impact it may have. The team is continuing to assess and review, but there is no ETA at the moment.

To schedule and email a dashboard refresh, the permission needed is : “Schedule Dashboards”. If you have this permission on your profile and still don't see this option. Please [create a case with Salesforce Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&language=en_us&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5)